# Adding multiple php files to yaml for google app engine

Tags: php, google-app-engine, yaml, handlers, app.yaml

Here are the contents of my yaml file:

application: myapp
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1

handlers:

- url: /static
  static_dir: static
- url: /suggest/.*
  script: suggestions.php
- url: /.*
  script: index.php

The static pages work fine, and so does index.php.

The problem is, I can't load my page for suggestions.php. I just get a blank white page.

On my local server it works perfectly, but when I deploy to appengine it's a blank page, so I think something is wrong with my handlers. Any advice?

Comment: Anything app engine logs? I would expect 404 if not handled.

Comment: is your 'suggestions.php' located in root folder??